# Most efficient way to display dynamic MKAnnotationViews in iOS7

Tags: ios7, mkmapview, geometry, drawrect, mkannotationview

I am trying to display many custom and dynamic circles on a `MKMapView` (up to 100 viewable at a time) that will vary in size, color, and opacity based on the data being passing to the `MKAnnotationView`.

I have custom `MKAnnotation` and `MKAnnotationView` classes currently and I have been exploring the numerous different ways to display these dynamically but I am not sure which one would deliver the best user experience (both in terms of graphics and speed).

Below  are the ways I have currently explored (I am sure there are many more that I have not explored) and any advice on what path I should go down (and any code help) would be greatly appreciated:

1 - Scaling a single .png image image of a circle and simply scaling the image `frame` and adjusting the image `tintcolor` as needed.

2 - Using drawrect to draw a circle dynamically every time.

3 - Using `layer.cornerradius` to create a circle imageview that I color as needed

Update - Here is the code that seems to create the best edges (using the 'layer.cornerradius' option) I am just not sure if it will be the best for making hundreds of circles viewable at the same time.

```
CGRect  myFrame = self.frame;
myFrame.size.width = 100;
myFrame.size.height = 100;
self.frame = myFrame;
self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2;
self.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:1 saturation:1 brightness:1 alpha:.5]];
```

Comment: Only way to know what's more or less efficient is to write the app and run it and use Instruments. Otherwise, don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: @matt Very true and very good advice... just wanted to see if anybody had already been done this path before

Answer (score 1):

you may use Clustering of all MKannoation and display it according to zoom level and location.

It may not exactly same what you want but you can get some efficient way of displaying multiple mkannotation views with best user experience.

you can get example code of clustering from below link

**https://github.com/yinkou/OCMapView**

Hope it helps you.

Thank you.

Comment: I have looked there and at certain zoom levels I will do some aggregation (or clustering) but will want to display numerous points on the map at the same time even if I do end up clustering. Thanks for passing along that link... For those looking for clustering another project to look at in github is here:https://github.com/choefele/CCHMapClusterController